# How to generate the following SOAP XML request?

Tags: php, xml, soap, parameters

The SOAP API I am using, needs the request XML formatted as below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:functionName/>
        <UserID>WEB</UserID>
        <Attribute>
            <ID>83</ID>
            <Value>34343</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <ID>84</ID>
            <Value>45343</Value>
        </Attribute>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I have gone through almost all "multiple element" related questions here on StackOverflow but still can't figure it out.

Here is what I am trying at the moment:

```
$args = new ArrayObject();
$args->UserID = WEB;

$Attribute = new stdClass();
$Attribute->ID = 83;
$Attribute->Value = 34343;
$args->append(new SoapParam($Attribute, 'Attribute'));

$Attribute = new stdClass();
$Attribute->ID = 84;
$Attribute->Value = 45343;
$args->append(new SoapParam($Attribute, 'Attribute'));

$soapClient->functionName($args);
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to figure it out. Hope the below code helps someone:

```
$args = array();
$args[] = new SoapVar('WEB', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'UserID');

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->ID = 83;
$obj->Value = 34343;
$args[] = new SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Attribute');

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->ID = 84;
$obj->Value = 45343;
$args[] = new SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Attribute');

$soapClient->functionName(new SoapVar($args, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a WSDL to php generator as you'll deal with abstracted classes that match the required parameter and the operations so you won't have to figure out the correct syntax, it will be automaticcally done by the generated package.

Two generators:

- Mine: https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator
- From others: https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the links but I don't see how these will help with multiple elements with same name. I used both the generator but as far as I can tell, these just generate a bunch of classes (something similar to the anonymous objects I am creating with stdClass)

Comment: Normally, if you need multiple elements to be sent, you have to create a PHP array containing the items. If you generated the package, then assign an array to the attribute.